# Filter list items using tuple items

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to exclude the below tuple called as folder names from list of src_files:
output of src_files looks like this :

```
[u'Archive/', u'Archive/Backup_978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_300201_TEST.csv', u'Source/', u'Source/978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_64106_TEST2.csv', u'Source/978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_771618_TEST1.csv', u'Source/978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_991406_TEST1.csv', u'TEST.csv', u'Target/', u'Target/Matillion_Report.csv', u'Target/Rejected_978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_300201_TEST.csv', u'Target/Report_978f124418f1359d7b7e50db7295bbba_300201_TEST.csv']
```

This is the code I am trying:

```
folder_names = ('Source/','Archive/','Target/')        
    src_files = []        
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket('rampdataquality')
    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(file.key)
        src_files.append(file.key)
        
    print (src_files)
```

desired output is:
List of src_files with :

> Test.csv or any .csv file only removing everythin

Comment: just to clarify, you want to get rid of anything in the `src_files` that starts with any of `Source/`, `Archive/` or `Target/`?

Comment: yes codemos, True